# Why can't I set the color of the Bar Tint property in Xcode 13.1

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I have a simple storyboard project in Xcode 13.1 consisting of a table view controller embedded in a navigation controller and I want to set the color of the navigation bar to system blue. So I select the drop down list next to the Bar Tint property in the Attributes Inspector and select system blue but Interface Builder doesn't show the new color. It remain white.

Answer (score 2):

Under Appearances, select Standard and Scroll Edge. Under Standard Appearance set Background to systemBlueColor,  under Scroll Edge Appearance set Background to systemBlueColor.